# How to get the list of all font-families used on the site?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

My main goal is to remove unused **font-faces** (links to fonts). I must know all **font-families** that are actually used on the website and then I will remove all unused. Bingo ;)

Comment: @codesayan that code doesn't work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does it find fonts that aren't in use? Does it miss fonts that are in use? Please provide an example of a scenario in which it doesn't match the fonts correctly.

Comment: @someserj its working, Check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply paste that in console and press enter , you can get a alert popup with list of fonts ..

```
function styleInPage(css, verbose){
    if(typeof getComputedStyle== "undefined")
    getComputedStyle= function(elem){
        return elem.currentStyle;
    }
    var who, hoo, values= [], val,
    nodes= document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    L= nodes.length;
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        who= nodes[i];
        if(who.style){
            hoo= '#'+(who.id || who.nodeName+'('+i+')');
            val= who.style.fontFamily || getComputedStyle(who, '')[css];
            if(val){
                if(verbose) values.push([hoo, val]);
                else if(values.indexOf(val)== -1) values.push(val);
            }
            val_before = getComputedStyle(who, ':before')[css];
            if(val_before){
                if(verbose) values.push([hoo, val_before]);
                else if(values.indexOf(val_before)== -1) values.push(val_before);
            }
            val_after= getComputedStyle(who, ':after')[css];
            if(val_after){
                if(verbose) values.push([hoo, val_after]);
                else if(values.indexOf(val_after)== -1) values.push(val_after);
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}

alert(styleInPage('fontFamily'));// returns array:
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This did wonders for me! I was trying to track down a custom font used for a clients website and this saved me so much time!